# Glass state of water

Tags: condensed-matter, water, glass

There is a lot of works on **hard-sphere glasses** where the spheres or other particles are squeezed and fail to find the global energy minimum being jammed in amorphous state. Is it possible to form a water glass by (perhaps, quickly) compressing water to very high density?

Comment: This answer is related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/381615/170832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, water can form a "glassy" solid states, called [amorphous ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_ice).

Depending on conditions and formation process it can have quite different properties. In particular it is not necessary for it to be compressed to very high density: it is actually possible to obtain amorphous ice that is less dense than liquid water, by vapour deposition (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_ice#Low-density_amorphous_ice)). High-density forms also exist.

All known forms of amorphous ice are found at relatively low temperature (~100-160K). Therefore it is not found on earth outside laboratories, but it is quite common in space, in particular in the interstellar medium.